# Git in Amazon EC2 to local machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitolite, public-key, git-clone

I installed Git and Gitolite in a Amazon Instance EC2 according with the following steps :

Created a public key locally with and send it to the EC2:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp/local.pub
rsync -avr /tmp/local.pub -e "ssh -i my-ec2-key.pem" root@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:/tmp/local.pub
```

Then installed the Git and gitolite :

```
sudo apt-get install git gitolite git-daemon-run
```

and then created a account for the user of git in EC2:

```
sudo adduser --system --shell /bin/bash --gecos 'git version control' --group --disabled-password --home /home/git git
su git
cd /home/git
echo "PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH" > .bashrc
gl-setup /tmp/local.pub
```

When i tried to clone the repository from EC2 in a local machine with the following command it returned an error :

```
rui@rui:~/.ssh$ git clone git@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:testing.git

Cloning into 'testing'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried different approaches but in the end the error is the same.

Comment: gl-setup? That sound like a very old gitolite 2.0. Any chance you could try with a gitolite 3.5x?

Comment: I tried with gitolite with a more recent version and the error in the end is the same,i followed the http://gitolite.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of the things that you can look at:

- Your gitolite.conf in your gitolite-admin.git repo. Make sure the content is something like this.

  ```
  repo    gitolite-admin
          RW+     =   rui

  repo    testing
          RW+     =   @all
  ```
- In your gitolite-admin/keydir directory of the gitolite-admin.git repo check that your public key file is there.  Also that it matches the private key of the file your are using to connect.

I've set it up gitolite myself and it works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your instance and perform a quick update:

```
sudo yum update -y
```

Install git in your EC2 instance

```
sudo yum install git -y
```

Check git version

```
git version
```